# Hide all images except first one till page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider on my page which is implemented like this:

```
<ul class="slides" id="slides">
    <li class="slide"><a href=""><img src="1.jpg" title="" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li class="slide"><a href=""><img src="2.jpg" title="" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li class="slide"><a href=""><img src="3.jpg" title="" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li class="slide"><a href=""><img src="4.jpg" title="" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

If I load the page all images show at onces. Only after the entire pages was loaded the slider script gets triggered and hides all images but one.
I tried to fix it with CSS by giving the slider a certain height. Actually this works for desktop but not if I resize the browser window.

So I would like to write some kind of JavaScript that hides all images except the first one until the page is completely loaded.

I tried it with following script but it doesn't work

```
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery(".slides li:not(:first-child)").hide(function() {
    jQuery(".slides li:not(:first-child)").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hide the images with CSS, and show them in onload handler.

Comment: Why not just use CSS?

Comment: You could consider using a set timeout function to have the image load after a set number of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS

```
#slides li:not(:first-child) { display: none }
```

And then to show them on load

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".slides li:not(:first-child)").show();
});
```

Comment: There should be `#slides li:not(:first-child) { display: none }` in CSS instead, as `img:first-child` will apply to all of these images - they are first child in `a` element.